# mypy infer paramspec of function based on paramspec of first input

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, typing

I'm creating a function which will act as a factory for a class, here's how it will look:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")
def app_factory(app: Type[T], *args, **kwargs) -> T:
    ...
    return app(*args, **kwargs)

class App:
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: bool):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

app_instance = app_factory(app=App, a="string", b=True)
```

Would it be possible to dynamically give `app_factory` the typehints `a: str, b: bool` based on the first input arg `app`? In other words, is there any way to dynamically set ParamSpec of a function to be equal to one of the function input callables?

Comment: @Kound (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813064/kound) This is a followup to our previous discussion on copying input params from one function to another

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically give type hints" ? The idea of Python typing is that it is static. But if you want to tell your type checker that, if `arg` is an `App` then use the following typehints (here `a` and `b`), you could use [overloading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)

Comment: overloading would include specifying each *args and **kwargs for every single different variant of the input app, right? I don't think this would be good for me as the args and kwargs for each app are subject to change, and quite unpredictable

Comment: Yes, that's it. There may be another way that uses the `inspect` module to get the `__init__` parameters of `Type[T]`, similarly to what [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) and [typer](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer) do. But i'm not sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is doable because type-checker implementations should recognise `type[T]` as a subtype of `Callable[P, T]`, where `P` is the parameters type of `T`'s `__new__` or `__init__`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx
    T = t.TypeVar("T")
    P = t.ParamSpec("P")

def app_factory(app: cx.Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    return app(*args, **kwargs)

class App:
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: bool) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

```
>>> app_factory(app=App, a="string", b=True)  # OK
>>> app_factory(app=App, a="string", b=1) # mypy: Argument "b" to "app_factory" has incompatible type "int"; expected "bool" [arg-type]
```